# REST interface on ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: rest, maven, resteasy, activemq-artemis

I'm trying to add REST interface to ActiveMQ Artemis by building .war file with Maven following [Artemis REST interface](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/rest.html) documentation.
After .war file is generated I move it in `/opt/artemis/apache-artemis-2.13.0/web/` directory and start ActiveMQ Artemis.

I'm getting next exception when starting ActiveMQ Artemis:

```
WARN [org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext] Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@4cb702ce{/artemis-rest,file:///var/lib/test-broker/tmp/jetty-0_0_0_0-8161-artemis-rest_war-_artemis-rest-any-15304647904836420970.dir/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{/opt/artemis/apache-artemis-2.13.0/web/artemis-rest.war}: java.lang.RuntimeException: You must install RESTEasy as a Bootstrap Listener and it must be listed before this class
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.rest.integration.RestMessagingBootstrapListener.contextInitialized(RestMessagingBootstrapListener.java:39) [artemis-rest-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
```

Also, getting 503 on HTTP request `http://192.168.0.50:8161/artemis-rest/queues/test`:

```
HTTP ERROR 503 Service Unavailable
URI:    /artemis-rest/queues/test
STATUS: 503
MESSAGE:    Service Unavailable
SERVLET:    -
```

I don't have RESTeasy installed because I can't find out how to, so I've downloaded jar file for RESTeasy jaxrs version 3.13.0.Final and put it in `WEB-INF/lib` directory and also included dependency for it in `pom.xml`.

Let me show you my configuration:

pom.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>org.somebody</groupId>
   <artifactId>artemis-rest</artifactId>
   <packaging>war</packaging>
   <name>My App</name>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>3.13.0.Final</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.activemq.rest</groupId>
         <artifactId>artemis-rest</artifactId>
         <version>2.13.0</version>
         <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
               <groupId>*</groupId>
               <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
         </exclusions>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</project>
```

web.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
     see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app>
   <listener>
      <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
   </listener>

   <listener>
      <listener-class>org.apache.activemq.artemis.rest.integration.RestMessagingBootstrapListener</listener-class>
   </listener>

   <filter>
      <filter-name>Rest-Messaging</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
   </filter>

   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>Rest-Messaging</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
   <context-param>
        <param-name>rest.messaging.config.file</param-name>
        <param-value>file:///WEB-INF/rest-messaging.xml</param-value>
   </context-param>
</web-app>
```

rest-messaging.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
     see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<rest-messaging>
    <server-in-vm-id>0</server-in-vm-id> <!-- deprecated, use "url" -->
    <use-link-headers>false</use-link-headers>
    <default-durable-send>false</default-durable-send>
    <dups-ok>true</dups-ok>
    <topic-push-store-dir>topic-push-store</topic-push-store-dir>
    <queue-push-store-dir>queue-push-store</queue-push-store-dir>
    <producer-time-to-live>0</producer-time-to-live>
    <producer-session-pool-size>10</producer-session-pool-size>
    <session-timeout-task-interval>1</session-timeout-task-interval>
    <consumer-session-timeout-seconds>300</consumer-session-timeout-seconds>
    <consumer-window-size>-1</consumer-window-size> <!-- deprecated, use "url" -->
    <url>vm://0</url>
</rest-messaging>
```

If needed I can also attach `broker.xml`, `jolokia-access.xml` and `bootstrap.xml` files, but they seems OK to me. I found older question about this [here](http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/Artemis-and-RESTeasy-jar-files-td4736865.html), but it didn't help to resolve this.

In case you know some other approaches for adding REST interface to ActiveMQ Artemis please inform me.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using the REST interface vs. something more standard like STOMP?

Comment: Hi Justin. Request is to use REST (http,https). I also don't have a lot of information and knowledge yet.

Comment: What "request" are you talking about, and why is it to use http(s)?

Comment: It's a project request. One company is using REST on servers and another on devices and it is not possible (to tell them) to use STOMP instead of REST in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the REST documentation for ActiveMQ Artemis hasn't been validated or updated in awhile.

You can get everything you need in the war file and exclude most of what you *don't* need using this `pom.xml`:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>org.somebody</groupId>
   <artifactId>artemis-rest</artifactId>
   <packaging>war</packaging>
   <name>My App</name>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.activemq.rest</groupId>
         <artifactId>artemis-rest</artifactId>
         <version>2.13.0</version>
         <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
               <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
               <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
               <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate</groupId>
               <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
               <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
               <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.jboss.logmanager</groupId>
               <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
         </exclusions>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</project>
```

Be sure to add an in-vm acceptor to your `broker.xml`, e.g.:

```xml
      <acceptors>
         ...
         <acceptor name="invm">vm://0</acceptor>
      </acceptors>
```

Also, you can automatically include the REST configuration XML if you structure your project like this:

```
|-- pom.xml
`-- src
   `-- main
       `-- webapp
           `-- WEB-INF
               `-- web.xml
       `-- resources
           `-- rest.xml
```

Then you can reference it in your `web.xml` like this:

```xml
   <context-param>
        <param-name>rest.messaging.config.file</param-name>
        <param-value>rest.xml</param-value>
   </context-param>
```

In general I would recommend *against* using the ActiveMQ Artemis REST interface for 2 main reasons:

1. Your code will *not* be portable because the ActiveMQ Artemis REST interface is a custom (i.e. not standardized) interface.
2. The STOMP protocol is ubiquitous, simple, standarized, and can be used in almost every circumstance and environment where REST might be used.

I recommend you use STOMP in lieu of the ActiveMQ Artemis REST interface.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's working. Only noticed this error **This page contains the following errors:
error on line 1 at column 111: Namespace prefix atom on link is not defined
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.** when using `http://192.168.0.50:8161/artemis-rest/queues/test` in a browser. GET and POST are working fine when testing with curl.

Comment: Yes I got that using web browser.

Comment: The data returned by the REST interface is not meant to be viewed in a browser. It's really only meant for messaging clients. Therefore, you can ignore that error as it's not a genuine error.